# CompletableFuture: Unhandled exception type ExecutionException

Tags: java

I am trying to explore CompletableFuture in Java8, I wrote this simple example to consume a fake api but I am getting this compilation error, I added the try/catch block around that piece of code but I am still getting the same compilation error.

*** FakeAPI1 ***

```
package com.fake.api;

public class FakeAPI1 implements FakeAPI{

    @Override
    public void consume(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            System.out.println("Hello from FakeAPI1");
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Eat it silently");
        }
    }

    public String getRandomText(){
        System.out.println("getRandomText() @ FakeAPI1 was called ");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            return "Hello from FakeAPI1";
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Eat it silently");
        }
        return "Default message from FakeAPI1";
    }
}
```

*** CompletableFutureTest ***

```
package com.example.completablefuture;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.fake.api.FakeAPI1;

public class CompletableFutureTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws InterruptedException,ExecutionException {

        List<Future<FakeAPI1>> apis= 
                Arrays.asList(
                    new CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>(),
                    new CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>(),
                    new CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>()
                );

        Long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
             apis.stream()
                 //Compilation error is in the line below
                 //Unhandled exception type ExecutionException 
                 .map(api->api.get().getRandomText())
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());


        Long end= System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("CompletableFutureTest took " + (end-start) + " ms" );

    }

}
```

I added the try/catch block as per recommendation in the below answer, The compilation error is no longer showing up, but when I run the code it does not do anything, It seems like it is waiting on something ...

```
package com.example.completablefuture;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.fake.api.FakeAPI1;

public class CompletableFutureTest {

public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws InterruptedException,ExecutionException {

    List<CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>> apis= 
            Arrays.asList(
                new CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>(),
                new CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>(),
                new CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>()
            );

    Long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<String> result= apis.stream()
        .map(api-> {
            try {
                System.out.println("1");
                 api.get().getRandomText();
            }catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO: return something else or throw a runtime exception
                System.out.println("ExecutionException");
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                // TODO: return something else or throw a runtime exception
                System.out.println("InterruptedException");
            }
            return "NA";
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    result.stream()
          .forEach(System.out::println);

    Long end= System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("CompletableFutureTest took " + (end-start) + " ms" );

 }

 }
```

I added a Timeout parameter to the get() method and it started throwing InterruptedException

```
   package com.example.completablefuture;

   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
   import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
   import java.util.concurrent.Future;  
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
   import java.util.stream.Collectors;


   import com.fake.api.FakeAPI1;

public class CompletableFutureTest {

public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws InterruptedException,ExecutionException {

    List<CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>> apis= 
            Arrays.asList(
                new CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>(),
                new CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>(),
                new CompletableFuture<FakeAPI1>()
            );

    Long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<String> result= apis.stream()
        .map(api-> {
            try {
                System.out.println("about to call get() method ...");
                 api.get(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).getRandomText();
            }catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO: return something else or throw a runtime exception
                System.out.println("ExecutionException");
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                // TODO: return something else or throw a runtime exception
                System.out.println("InterruptedException");
            }catch(TimeoutException e){
                // TODO: return something else or throw a runtime exception
                System.out.println("InterruptedException");
            }
            return "NA";
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    result.stream()
          .forEach(System.out::println);

    Long end= System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("CompletableFutureTest took " + (end-start) + " ms" );

}
}

about to call get() method ...
InterruptedException
about to call get() method ...
InterruptedException
about to call get() method ...
InterruptedException
NA
NA
NA
CompletableFutureTest took 3062 ms
```

Comment: Unhandled exception type ExecutionException

Comment: It is a compilation error not an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not catching the exception in the right place. `map()` expects a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/function/Function.html). And a Function can't throw any checked exception. So you need

```
.map(api-> {
    try {
        return api.get().getRandomText());
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO: return something else or throw a runtime exception
    }
})
```

Comment: I added the try/catch blow as you recommend but it gave me this compilation error : This method must return a result of type Object . I added a return statement after the catch block but I got same compilation error again.

Comment: Hard to explain why your code has a problem without seeing your code. You must return **something**. Not just return.

Comment: Don't add screenshots. Post the code, as text, and post the exact and complete error from the compiler, as text. Also, read the javadoc of get(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--. It doesn't only throw ExecutionException. So you must handle the other exception, too.

Comment: I removed the screenshots as per your recommendations, I added another catch block to catch the other exception, the compilation error is gone now but when I run the code it does nothing, it executes the line " System.out.println("1");"  nothing happen after that, seems like it is waiting on something.

Answer (score 2):

When using a `CompletableFuture`, you should use the `join()` method rather than `get()`.  They are functionally identical (in non-exceptional cases), but the former doesn't throw checked exceptions.